# Evisa (Tourist) for turkey, I have a valid Austrailian visa will that help?

Tags: indian-citizens, turkey, e-visas

I am Indian passport holder, I have a valid Visa of Australia and I want to travel to Turkey, does this Australian visa help in processing the Visa ?

Answer (score 2):

No, an Australian visa is not a valid supporting document for a Turkish e-visa.

If you apply on the [Turkish Govt. e-visa website](https://www.evisa.gov.tr) and select India - Ordinary Passport, you get a list of pre-requisites (emphasis mine)

> - My passport covers the period that I will be staying in Turkey.
> - I can prove that I hold a return ticket, hotel reservation and at least 50 $ per each day of my stay.
> - I am travelling for the purposes of tourism or business.
> - I have a valid Supporting Document (**Valid visa OR valid residence permit from one of the Schengen Countries, USA, UK or Ireland**).
>     E-visas are not accepted as supporting documents.
> - I confirm that I meet each and every one of the conditions listed above.